# Distribute Points on Faces / Set Material node performance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am seeing a huge performance impact in my "Distribute Points on Faces" node when used with a large geometry surface input (1km x 1km).

Node timing show it takes up to 300ms, but in reality Blender interface freezes ~15 seconds on every interaction, I had to reduce density to around 0.1 for Blender to become interactive again.

While I fully understand this is to be expected, I wonder what impact its performance the most. Is there a faster equivalent if my goal is to distribute geometry across a certain part of surface? (Imagine: trees on ground but not in water.)

(I am using Blender 3.1 beta by the way)

(Update: a screenshot on node timing, `Distribute Points on Faces` being the mostly costly node, `Set Material` being second.)

[image: node timing]

Comment: Is this just point instancing or are you creating mesh instances afterwards ?

Comment: @Gorgious I updated a screenshot on this, the main cost is `Distribute Points on Faces` and `Set Material`, both seem related to the size of my terrain.

Comment: Yeha I think the hiccup you experience is the actual instantiation of geometry, not the creation of points. Do you realize the instances afterwards ?

Comment: @Gorgious I didn't realize them, I have only joined the terrain geometry with these instanced cubes. But node timing suggest the main cost is at distribute though? Was it misleading then? And I have tried the same blend file on both Windows (with RTX 3080 + pretty new AMD) and macOS (Intel GPU + i5), both perform roughly the same, so what's the bottleneck here?

Comment: I think you shouldn't trust 100% the node timing. My instinct is that only the mathematical, geometrical evaluation is timed, but there is no accurate way to time the actual instantiation in the 3D world because it has intricate dependencies, for instance if your mesh is part of a boolean operation in another object, it won't be taken into consideration in the node timing but it will take a considerable amount of time to compute

Comment: @Gorgious I tested it without the instancing node, the performance is still bad, it is really the distribute node.